# What's the best way to return Obj.key1.key2...keyN?

Tags: javascript

One must check Obj.key1, Obj.key2, ..., Obj.key(n-1) if they're undefined.

The normal convention would be:

```
if (typeof Obj !== 'undefined') {
  if (typeof Obj.key1 !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof Obj.key1.key2 !== 'undefined')
      ...
        if (typeof Obj.key1.key2...keyN !== 'undefined') {
          return Obj.key1.key2...keyN
        }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `typeof`?

Comment: What if any of them is `undefined`?

Comment: Consider using a loop.

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be 'typeof' instead of 'typedef'

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so, please accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally that code is shortened a bit into

```
if (obj && obj.key1 && obj.key1.key2 && obj.key1.key2.key3) {
    return obj.key1.key2.key3.key4;
}
```

because `undefined` is also falsy and any object is instead truthy.

The shorter but IMO logically uglier alternative is

```
try { return obj.key1.key2.key3.key4; } catch(e) { }
```

that may be is acceptable if you never use Javascript properties as it can hide errors in non-trivial accessors.

Comment: This does work for javascript and apparently i'm doing this one. I just find it's redundant every time I want to return the final key.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x;
try {
    x = Obj.key1.key2.key3.key4....keyN;
}
catch(err) {
   console.warn( err );
}
```

Comment: @Whathaveyoutried: I'm not sure. I thought the point was that we don't want to repeat the undefined check boilerplate for every key.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this piece of code, I call it resolve property.

```js
function resolveProperty(object, property, deep) {
    if(typeof deep === 'undefined') {
        deep = true;
    }

    if(typeof property === 'string' && deep) {
        property = property.split('.');
    }

    if(!object) {
        return null;
    }

    if(!deep) {
        property = Array.isArray(property) ? property[0] : property;

        if(typeof property === 'undefined') {
            return object;
        } else {
            return object[property];
        }
    }

    return resolveProperty(object[property.shift()], property, property.length > 1);
}



$('#results').append(' > ' + resolveProperty({ a: {}}, 'a.b') + '<br />');
$('#results').append(' > ' + resolveProperty({ a: {}}, 'a.b.c.d') + '<br />');
$('#results').append(' > ' + resolveProperty({ a: { b: 1 }}, 'a.b') + '<br />');
$('#results').append(' > ' + resolveProperty({ a: { b: 1 }}, 'a.b.c') + '<br />');
$('#results').append(' > ' + resolveProperty({ a: { b: { c: '123' } }}, 'a.b.c') + '<br />');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results" />
```

It will actualy resolve the property so you can compare to undefined like

```
if(resolveProperty(yourObject, 'a.b.c.d.e')) {
    //good to go
}
```

PS.: You might wanna replace the array verification method (`Array.isArray`) if you will run this code in the browser since it is not default (cross browser).

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily recommend this solution, but you could do

```
function getPath(obj, path) {
    return path.split(.).reduce(function(val, seg) {
        return val && typeof val === 'object' && val[seg];
    }, obj);
}
```

Now you can just do

```
getPath(Obj, 'key1.key2.key3...keyN')
```

If you are a CoffeeScript user, you can use the so-called "existential operator":

```
Obj.key1?.key2?.key3?...keyN
```